My Nodemon Server is crashing every time i am using a piece of code
I am writing a server for my realtime collab IDE and this is my backend, Here is the full backend index.js code
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const {Server} = require('socket.io');

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server);

const userSocketMap = {};

const getAllConnectedClients = (roomId) => {
    return Array.from(io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(rommId) || []).map(
        (socketId) =>{
            return{
                socketId,
                username: userSocketMap[socketId],
            };
        }
    ) //map
};

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    //console.log(`User connected: ${socket.id}`);
    socket.on("join", ({ roomId, username }) => {
        userSocketMap[socket.id] = username;
        socket.join(roomId);
        const clients = getAllConnectedClients(roomId);
        console.log(clients);
    });
});

const PORT = process.nextTick.PORT || 5000;
server.listen(PORT, () => console.log('server is running'));


Here this area is constantly crashing node.js
    socket.on("join", ({ roomId, username }) => {
        userSocketMap[socket.id] = username;
        socket.join(roomId);
        const clients = getAllConnectedClients(roomId);
        console.log(clients);

the error that is coming is
"[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting..."
I tried re-importing almost everything but it didnt help

What the exact error you are getting when server crashes?

@Subha added the error in the question, kindly check :)

it would be roomId in this io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(rommId) and process.env.PORT || 5000 since that is how .env variable gets accessed.Fix these and let me know.

@Subha Thank you for the advice and yes it worked!!!! Once again thank you so much!!

Yeah,welcome you are.
